# symbols in the parameter names of SQL stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting some errors when trying to create a parameter for s stored procedure in SQL 2008 where parameter name has the symbol `&` in the name.

What is the correct syntax for something like `@Column&Title`?

Have tried `@[Column&Title]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need the ampersand?

Comment: @sd_dracula . . . I believe the problem is that `@` is not allowed in a delimited object name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027(v=sql.100).asp).  As such, there is no way to define a delimited parameter or local variable.  This surprises me, but I guess I never tried such a thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ampersand is not a valid character to use in a variable name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

Comment: Simple answer... don't use & use And

Comment: Thanks. Was just wondering if it's possible because it IS allowed in the column name.